# Symfony/Apache - High CPU and RAM usage

Tags: php, ajax, apache, symfony

I'm currently working on Symfony project combined with HTTPD. Server CentOS.
I use twig views and PHP controllers. I'm facing a huge performance problem.

When I call a controller, in any way (return view, AJAX...), my RAM rises to 20% and CPU to ~15%. I can see that with the command "top" and HTTPD process.

```
%Cpu(s):  5,5 us,  1,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st

KiB Mem :  1883696 total,    80668 free,  1623492 used,   179536 buff/cache

KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  1796076 free,   301072 used.    67696 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM    TIME+   COMMAND

10992 apache  20  0    2533000 363684  8696 S 12,6   19,3  15:59.17  httpd
```

I don't understand why a simple ajax call do that. For example :

```
$.ajax({                                                            
    type: "GET",
    data: {                                                         
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2
    },
    url: "{{ path('my_path') }}",         
    success: function (response) {}
```

And PHP :

```
public function my_pathAction(Request $request)
{
    self::instancierRepository(array("Services"));

    $param1 = $request->get('param1 ');
    $param2 = $request->get('param2');

    $liste = $this->repositoryServices->findServices($param1, $param2);

    $response = new Response( json_encode( $liste ));

    return new Response($response->getContent());
}
```

This kind of code makes raise the CPU 13% and RAM 20% with one apache process visible with top.
Needless to say that with 5 pages open together, CPU up to 70-80%, then it is impossible to use the application because I call this kind of AJAX requests every 10 secondes.

Symfony profiler : 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGjLk.png)

Maybe I forgot something important with Apache configuration or Symfony.
Thank's for help.
Bye.

Comment: Well, what's `findServices` doing? It might look like a simple function call, but that could spiral into dozens of expensive nested database queries, or whatever. Have you tried *profiling* your code to see exactly where the CPU cycles are spent?

Comment: This function doesn't change CPU usage. I tried to remove it, and thats didn't change. For the profiler, I only use from Symfony. I edit my message.

Comment: You are redundant there. There is no need to create two instances of Response. Just `return new Response( json_encode( $liste ));` or `return new JsonResponse($liste)` . 
Also, how big is the array $liste? If it's too big then it might be CPU intensive.

Comment: It's revised. $liste isn't big, Like this   [{"id":1,"nom":"Bourse","guichet":[{"id":1,"numGuichet":3,"statut":"Ouvert","compteur":[{"id":1,"numTicket":22,"date":{"date":"2017-10-23}
{"id":2,"numGuichet":1,"statut":"Indisponible","compteur":[{"id":2,"numTicket":18,"date":{"date":"2017-10-22}

Comment: Are you doing this check on `dev` or `prod` environment? Also, what is your PHP version and do you use opcache? 
Try running the app in `prod` env as you will see big improvements because Symfony won't need to rebuild it's cache files on every request.

Comment: I did in prod and yeah, performances are better, but still too high. I don't use opcache, if you think it can help me, I will try it.